# On the existence of a non-regular language $L$ such that $L^2\in \text{Reg}$?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Is there a non-regular language $L$ such that the language $L^2$ is regular? 
Nothing comes to my mind. What's your proposition ?

Comment: What is your definition of $L^2$?

Comment: $L^2=L \cdot L$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a one-letter alphabet $\{a\}$ and let $L = \{a^{n^2} \mid n \geqslant 0 \} \cup \{a^{2n+1} \mid n \geqslant 0 \}$. Then $L^2 = a^*$, a regular language, and I let you verify that $L$ is not regular.

Comment: Ok, I try to check it: $L\cap \{a^{2n}|n\ge 0\} =\{a^{n^2}|\text{ n is even}\} $   It is sufficient now to use **exactly** the same proof (pumping lemma) as in case $\{a^{n^2}|n\ge 0\}$        OK ?

Comment: @user220688 Sounds like a good approach, yes.

Comment: thanks you very much, I invite to others threads in this subject :)